# What does heap analytics' script code do?

Tags: javascript, events, analytics, web-analytics

So Heap Analytics tells me to paste this code in order to use their product -

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  window.heap=window.heap||[];heap.load=function(a){window._heapid=a;var b=document.createElement("script");b.type="text/javascript",b.async=!0,b.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https:":"http:")+"//cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap.js";var c=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];c.parentNode.insertBefore(b,c);var d=function(a){return function(){heap.push([a].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments,0)))}},e=["identify","track"];for(var f=0;f<e.length;f++)heap[e[f]]=d(e[f])};
  heap.load("YOUR_APP_ID");
</script>
```

What does this code do? (barring all the app id stuff).

I found something similar in the open source analytics.js

```
<script type="text/javascript">
window.analytics||(window.analytics=[]),window.analytics.methods=["identify","track","trackLink","trackForm","trackClick","trackSubmit","page","pageview","ab","alias","ready","group","on","once","off"],window.analytics.factory=function(t){return function(){var a=Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);return a.unshift(t),window.analytics.push(a),window.analytics}};for(var i=0;i<window.analytics.methods.length;i++){var method=window.analytics.methods[i];window.analytics[method]=window.analytics.factory(method)}window.analytics.load=function(t){var a=document.createElement("script");a.type="text/javascript",a.async=!0,a.src=("https:"===document.location.protocol?"https://":"http://")+"d2dq2ahtl5zl1z.cloudfront.net/analytics.js/v1/"+t+"/analytics.min.js";var n=document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];n.parentNode.insertBefore(a,n)},window.analytics.SNIPPET_VERSION="2.0.8",
window.analytics.load("YOUR_WRITE_KEY");
window.analytics.page();
</script>
```

Is that doing something similar? (at a glance it looks like it)

Comment: A tool like http://jsbeautifier.org/ can help clear up some mysteries like this.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here's the snippet as of May 2021:

```
window.heap = window.heap || [], heap.load = function (e, t) {
  window.heap.appid = e, window.heap.config = t = t || {};
  var r = document.createElement("script");
  r.type = "text/javascript", r.async = true, r.src = "https://cdn.heapanalytics.com/js/heap-" + e + ".js";
  var a = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0];
  a.parentNode.insertBefore(r, a);
  for (var n = function (e) {
    return function () {
      heap.push([e].concat(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0)));
    };
  }, p = ["addEventProperties", "addUserProperties", "clearEventProperties", "identify", "resetIdentity", "removeEventProperty", "setEventProperties", "track", "unsetEventProperty"], o = 0; o < p.length; o++) heap[p[o]] = n(p[o]);
};

heap.load("YOUR_APP_ID");
```

First, it defines a global `heap` object.

Then it defines a `heap.load` method. `heap.load` first sets your app id `e` and options `t` to the `window.heap` object for future use.

Next, it creates a new script element to load the heap.js tracking script. heap.js sends event data to Heap.

After heap.js starts loading, `heap.load` stubs out the following methods so that they can be called before heap.js finishes loading:

```js
heap.addEventProperties
heap.addUserProperties
heap.clearEventProperties
heap.identify
heap.resetIdentity
heap.removeEventProperty
heap.setEventProperties
heap.track
heap.unsetEventProperty
```

Lastly, the script calls the previously-defined `heap.load` with your app id. :)

You can read more on [Heap's developer documentation](https://developers.heap.io/docs).

Answer (score 1):

It is printing an inline Javascript call to the page that references, loads, and initializes the off-site analytics tracking script from it with parameters specific to your website (like tracking options and ID).

Comment: ahh ok - so is that what the second script is also doing? Or is that actually adding event handlers?

Comment: It looks to me like it's defining custom events to be tracked, or at least initializing them.  It's worth noting that injecting script this way (rather than just referencing the external script in the usual fashion) allows it to be loaded asynchrononously and is protocol independent (so you don't have to worry about `http` vs `https`)